# How to require a block in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

Is there any built in way to require that a block be passed to a Ruby method?  I realize I can just raise an exception if `block_given?` is false, but is there some nicer way to do it?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Simply by using `yield`.

If you include `yield` in a method, and a block is *not* given, it throws an error.

Put this in a file and run it:

```
def needs_block
    yield
end

needs_block
```

It will throw an error like this:

```
LocalJumpError: no block given
    from (irb):14:in `needs_block'
    from (irb):16
```

Comment: Well that was way too easy :) Thanks!

Answer (score 17):

```
raise 'need block' unless block_given?
```

Comment: This is the best answer, since it has no side effects (i.e. calling the block).

Answer (score 1):

If your method required a block, Ruby will prompt it. The raise keyword doesn't require a block, it only prompts a message for handling an Exception.

It could be a method like the above example

```
def needs_block
 yield
end
```

needs_block

Or you could require a Proc

```
def needs_block(&Proc)
    proc.call
end
```

Anyway, adding raise block_given? would be nice.

[Here says](http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/ruby_exceptions.html):

> "The raise method is from the Kernel module. By default, raise creates
>   an exception of the RuntimeError class. To raise an exception of a
>   specific class, you can pass in the class name as an argument to
>   raise".