# Why does Ruby use yield?

Tags: ruby

I am new to Ruby. I have used a lot of C# and JavaScript which allow higher-order functions and I typically use them on a daily basis.

Ruby seems a little strange to me though. An `each` function might look like:

```
def each
    @items.each do |item|
        yield(item)
    end
end

items.each { |item| puts item }
```

Yet Ruby also has some support for higher-order functions. The above could be rewritten to something like:

```
def each(proc)
    @items.each do |item|
        proc.call item
    end
end

items.each -> (item) { puts item }        # Or...
items.each lambda { |item| puts item }
```

Or even:

```
def each(&proc)
    @items.each do |item|
        proc.call item
    end
end

# No difference in syntax.
items.each { |item| puts item }
```

Which is more on par with most other languages, and is just a few characters longer. Instead of explicitly passing in a block, everything seems to use `yield`.

`yield` itself seems crazy, magical, and mysterious. After all, it's going to the origin of the call and grabbing a block immediately following the call. This seems bizarre and unnatural, and I'm not aware of any parallel of this feature in another language.

So what's the deal with `yield`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Yield Passes Objects to a Method's Block

> [Yield is] going to the origin of the call and grabbing a block immediately following the call.

Not really. `yield` passes an argument to a block; it doesn't "grab a block" or do anything with it. In other words, this:

```
def foo; yield self; end
foo { |x| x.inspect }                                       
# => "main"
```

Here, `yield` isn't doing anything but passing an argument to the block that is passed into the `foo` method. Every Ruby method supports an optional block—except when a block is actually mandatory—so the only "magic" is that the language allows a block to be passed even when it isn't explicitly declared as part of the method signature.

#### Further Examples

To see this implicit signature in action, consider this:

```
def foo; puts block_given?; end
foo { |x| x.inspect }
```

which will print "true" and return `nil`, which is the expected return value from the `puts` method.

Of course, without `yield` the block doesn't do anything at all. For example:

```
def foo; end
foo { |x| x.inspect }
# => nil
```

Comment: @AndrewMarshall A block may be mandatory for the method to execute properly, and a LocalJumpError exception may be raised if `block_given? == false`. Consider `def foo; yield; end; foo` and see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2308948/how-to-require-a-block-in-ruby for some related discussion on this issue.

Answer (score 14):

## Yield is Syntax Sugar

This example of yield:

```
def do_something_for_each(array)
  array.each do |el|
    yield(el)
  end
end
```

Is just syntax sugar for:

```
def do_something_for_each(array, &block)
  array.each do |el|
    block.call(el)
  end
end
```

Pick the syntax you like and run wild with it.

Comment: @Marc, Any guess about why?

Comment: @LBg: Capturing the block (with &block) is costly. It needs to create an object and that object must be able to live outside of its scope. For example `do_something` could store it and call it later.

Answer (score 4):

One advantage of `yield` is it also lets you use `next` (like `continue`) and `break`. In other languages, for `next`, you might have to use `return`, and for `break`, you might have to (ab)use exceptions. It is arguably nicer to have built-in support for these sorts of operations.

Answer (score 1):

In most cases, you execute the block right there in the method, using
**yield**.

The block is passed straight into the method, and the method can then
call back to the block with the **yield** keyword.

```
def a_method(a, b)
a + yield(a, b)
end
a_method(1, 2) {|x, y| (x + y) * 3 } # => 10
```

When you call back to the block, you can provide values for its arguments,
just like you do when you call a method. Also, like a method, a
block returns the result of the last line of code it evaluates.