# How to prohibit a block (require that no block argument is given) in Ruby

Tags: ruby, syntax, semantics

I defined this method:

```
# @return [Array<String>] items
def produce_items
  ["foo", "bar", "baz"]
end
```

A correct usage would be, obviously,

```
produce_items.each do |i|
  puts i
end
```

But I wrote this, which *silently does nothing*:

```
produce_items do |i|
  puts i
end
```

Is there a way to declare `produce_items` in such a way that my incorrect usage produces an error/exception? If [MRI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruby_MRI) cannot do it, can an alternative interpreter do it? Can a static analysis tool like [RuboCop](https://github.com/bbatsov/rubocop) or [ruby-lint](https://github.com/YorickPeterse/ruby-lint) do it?

I suspect it may be hard because there are common idioms where methods take an *optional* block:

```
def block_optional_implicitly
  if block_given?
    puts "Got a block"
    yield
  else
    puts "Did not get a block"
  end
end

def block_optional_explicitly(&block)
  unless block.nil?
    puts "Got a block"
    block.call
  else
    puts "Did not get a block"
  end
end
```

(This is a reverse of the question [How to require a block in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2308948/how-to-require-a-block-in-ruby))

Comment: You could always `raise YikesBlock if block_given?`

Comment: You can selectively raise an exception when method doesn't expect it. But, you have to be cautious enough to not to do it in those methods which might actually require a block (optionally or otherwise).

Answer (score 5):

Yep, no way of doing this in ruby, except the `block_given?` checks all over the code.

Passing a block to a method that doesn't expect it does no harm. Besides something not happening (because you forgot the `.each`). This should be covered by unit tests. You kill two birds with one stone: make your code more regression-proof *and* don't get to insert `fail "unexpected block" if block_given?` into every method of your app.